# Some images not able to display in html

Tags: php, html, image

The images broken if the name are not in English, while all of the other images with English naming are able to display in the webpage.

[image]

The broken images are able to display if I enter the file path location in browser

**For example** www.myserver.com/files/image/你好.png

In what situation the image will not be able to display. All the file are store in the same directory and there is no problem with the linking of the files as all the files are using the same address to display.

**Update**
For some reason, I'm using php code to validate the URL of image which causes the file name pass from database did not encode properly. I simply add `mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");` in the .php file then all images work fine.

Comment: check the image is located in the respective folder

Comment: Apply proper URL encoding. Better yet, avoid this kind of situation if at all possible (keyword _file name transliteration_  or similar.)

Comment: @Muthusamy No problem with the location, all images are in same folder

Comment: @CBroe Trying to understand URL encoding part, not so familiar with this one

Comment: If there is any mistake in this question, please drop a message instead of downvote without telling me what is wrong with my question

Comment: The file name you have shown, properly URL encoded, would be `%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD.png` - so try if that works first of all.

Comment: Thanks for the precious advice, I've updated the solution in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with encoding used in browser such as "UTF-8" and others. Look in that direction or just rename all images to english

Comment: Trying to understand URL encoding part, not so familiar with this one. Due to some reason, rename the image name is not a choice for me lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the character encoding to a Korean standard with a meta tag:

`<meta charset="EUC-KR">` in the head of your document.

Here's a [reference](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) and further explanation of character sets and encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the language code to `cn` or, `kr`

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="cn">
...
</html>`

Comment: It's not working, I tried both  `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="cn">` and  `<html lang="cn">`.  By the way, I'm doing with jsp and spring MVC, perhaps there is different solution?